# Plot vertex as image in Igraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, igraph

I'm wondering if it is possible to plot a vertex as image (loaded from a file or directly) in Igraph. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitley possible in the R version of iGraph using the raster function, however a brief search did not reveal any implementation of this function in Python (it's not in the igraph documentation anyway).

If this is essential to your work, then I would consider switching to R, or possibly another tool such as Gephi. For Python, however, you might consider using something like [pyvis](https://pypi.org/project/pyvis/). This package is small but powerful in terms of visualization. I've been playing around with it over the past few days and its very easy to display a graph with pictures as nodes, and it comes with the added benefit of providing interactive functioning. Take a look at the tutorial [here](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), which will highlight what this package can provide.